# Can multiple programs be signed using one blackberry signing key?

Tags: blackberry, code-signing

When registering to have an application [signed by Blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847208/blackberry-application-signing), do you need to request a new key for each program that uses the signed apis? Or can you reuse the same key for multiple applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same key for multiple applications.  The only restriction is that a signing key is only supposed to be installed on one machine.

Comment: Are there any limitations?? How many applications can be signed with single key???