# Install a test app on BlackBerry

Tags: eclipse, blackberry

How do I install a test app developed using Eclipse on a BlackBerry?

Comment: This should get you going: [Steps to test a J2ME application on a Blackberry device](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Steps-to-test-a-J2ME-application-on-a-Blackberry-device/m-p/219729)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you using Eclipse for BB development, you must use [Plugin for Eclipse](https://www.blackberry.com/Downloads/contactFormPreload.do?code=DC727151E5D55DDE1E950767CF861CA5&dl=AC44596FD197101932FFB572DFBC129C) and [BB simulator](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/resources/simulators.jsp). In this way you just build your application and run/debug it from IDE. IDE automatically run simulator and deploy your cod to simulator.

In other cases, there are 3 ways to run your *.cod application on BB device:

1. Using [javaloader](http://www.blackberryhowto.com/content.php?article.32)
2. Using [DesktopManager](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/services/desktop/)
3. Directly from simulator (only for simulator!). File\Load Java Application\Choose your cod, and your application appears in Downloads directory.
4. Using OTA (Over-The-Air) installation(for web-installation).

Note, that if you use for, example, Crypto API or Persistent storage API, before install your application on **real device**, you must [sign it with SignatureTool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847208/blackberry-application-signing).